# Is there a word that describes 'the study of punctuation'?

Tags: punctuation

I am thinking about this in a non-grammatical, non-paleographic, and non-linguistic sense, although I am aware punctuation is studied as part of all these (and other) fields. I am interested in punctuation as a field of study, in and of itself. Does such a word exist?

Some literature which leads me to think that there is no such word, based on its presence and intrinsic use in other fields, includes the following passages:

- Geoffrey Nunberg's *The Linguistics of Punctuation* (1990): “Punctuation is ... a linguistic subsystem.”
- Robert Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style* (2004): "[P]unctuation is cold notation; it is not frustrated speech; it is typographic code."

... but I would be very interested if someone might suggest any other convincing answer.

**Most relevant answer (as of 12.11.2014) from @user3306356: Stigmeology, relating to the art and use of punctuation.**

Comment: As far as I know, there is no more specific term than "study of punctuation". **Orthography** includes punctuation among other things, as the closest single word apart from "punctuation" itself.

Comment: I don't think there is, but now that you have raised it some smart Alec is sure to suggest something. Some people are obsessive about creating new words (often, one suspects, those less capable with the old ones). How about *punctuatronics*?

Comment: @WS2 Or simply _punctuology_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Or even more simply *punctuation*? 'He is a student/professor of punctuation'. The problem is that people don't think a field of study is important unless it is a long word.

Answer (score 6):

maybe a bit of a stretch, but anyhow...

**stigmeology**

> The art of proper punctuation
>
> -*[Grandiloquent Dictionary](http://www.islandnet.com/%7Eegbird/dict/s.htm)*

Comment: Great word, thanks! Also found this:

*Stigmeological - Related to ... punctuation marks and the use of [the] same. (Serifs are but one part of the skeleton of a letter that helps visual poets determine the visual look of the verbal and stigmeological characters they use). 

[Use in sentence]: By reading this story, we were supposed to learn how to punctuate -- to learn, specifically, a new stigmeological skill: how to use quotation marks.* Source: http://neologisms.us/scripts/show_alpha_detail.php?id=2248

Answer (score 1):

Why not ***punctuation***?

*He is a student/professor of punctuation*.